# How do I bind touch manipulation to a UIElement property on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, uielement

I would like to have a property of a `UIElement` be modified when the user swipes vertically on the screen in Windows Phone 7. I can see how to do it using the `OnManipulationDelta` override but it seems like that should be a Xaml binding of some sort that would accomplish it in mark-up.

Can you bind properties to touch manipulations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [an example](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/windows_phone_7/archive/2010/07/19/wp7-gesture-recognizer-and-behavior-triggers.aspx) of how you might go about doing that.